# Android Facebook login not showing Login success dialog

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I want to implement share post functionality in my android app.
For that I need to first check if user is logged in and then show a user Login dialogue.

After a successful login, I will show a Share dialog.
When I click login button it automatically logs in and does not show the Login dialog.

What am I doing wrong?

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
// Callback registration
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"in LoginResult on success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"in LoginResult on cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"in LoginResult on error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: "it automatically logs in and does not show Login dialog" -> Why is that a problem? If user has already authorized your app, user is logged in automatically

Comment: Its a problem, I guess, because a confirmation dialog is required; notifying the user of the permissions the App will be using.

Answer (score 0):

You should intercept the login callback in onActivityResult.

Comment: SDK 4 behaves differently.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @inmyth mentioned above, you need to forward the login result (fail, success, or canceled) back to the `CallbackManager` via `onActivityResult()` like this:

```
/*Then in onActivityResult() forward the login results to the callbackManager created in onCreate():
   Every activity and fragment that you integrate with the FacebookSDK Login or
   Share should forward onActivityResult to the callbackManager.*/
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

After doing this you can now execute desired code in in `onSuccess()` `onCancel()` and `onFail()`